# js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version After Update to Node 5

Tags: node.js

Since I've update NodeJS to version 5.0.0 on my Mac OS X I'm getting those two lines every time I run my app:

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

I've try to delete `node_modules` and run `sudo npm cache clean' and then`sudo npm install` but it didn't solve the problem.